# Toggling "favorites" on the network profile

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, favorites-tab

On your personal profile on each StackExchange site, it is possible to uncheck questions marked as favorites.

That is not possible on the network profile.

I guess this is because it would be updating data across StackExchange sites, but that favorite button is just so tempting to click.

Is it possible to make it clickable?

Comment: Note: This tab no longer exists on the network profile, since [the Bookmarks feature (the renamed version of Favorites) was replaced with the Saves feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/335251). As such, I'm closing this as no longer reproducible.